# Get the point that corresponds to 1/3rd the distance from p1 to p2

Tags: math, linear-algebra, algebra

So for example, if we have p1 = (x1,y1) and p2 = (x2,y2) and I want to find the point that corresponds to 1/3rd the distance from p1 and p2 that lies in the line formed by p1 and p2, then what formula would I use? Having a brainfart right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same one as for any other position:

```
p(t) = a*(1-t) + b*t
```

where 0 <= t <= 1 gives all points on a line between vectors "a" and "b"/

In your case

```
p = (x1, y1)* (1-1/3) + (x2,y2) * 1/3
```

which is how some other answers look like.

Comment: yup this is what I was forgetting. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Use Section Formula . Read [here](http://www.learnnext.com/lesson/CBSE-X-Maths-Section-Formula.htm).

You have to find a point(x,y) that divides line in ratio 1:3 .

```
x = (x2+3*x1)/4
y = (y2+3*y1)/4
```

If the line segment is of distance d units then  point **(x,y)** lies at distance d/3 from **(x1,y1)** and
distance 2d/3 from point **(x2,y2)**

Answer (score 3):

If A is the vector to the first point, and B is the vector to the second point, then the point you want is
      `(2A + B) / 3`

This works because the point one third of the way between A and B, vectorially, is the vector A + one third of the vector between A and B:

That is `A + 1/3(B-A)`

Algebra does the rest.

Answer (score 1):

The point p3 = (x3, y3) 1/3rd of the distance is:

```
x3 = (2 * x1 + x2) / 3    
y3 = (2 * y1 + y2) / 3
```

Comment: is that general in a sense that  a/b*(2*x1+x2) would return the point in line at which the distance is a/b from p1 to p2? Like if I wanted to get the distance that corresponds to 2/3rd the distance instead of 1/3rd, would the same formula suffice?

Comment: Use `x3 = (1 - a/b) * x1 + (a/b) * x2`, assuming a and/or b are floats. (In many languages, 1/3 evaluates to zero!)